# How to stop crash issues in play console when testing an app

Tags: android

My app is in production in play store. When I am experimenting with some new features in my app locally and get any kind of issues in it then those issues are reflecting in Crashes in Google Play Console. How to stop issues reflecting in Google Play Console when I am testing it locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `applicationId` in app/gradle for the debug mode, test using debug apk and upload the signed release apk on console.

This way, only the release apk's logs will be shown on console.

But you have to handle situations, when you app's functionality depends on the specific `applicationId`, like api calls or `google-services.json` file